# Matplotlib basemaps draws two parallels on stereographic projection

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

This is my first question on Stack Overflow, so my apologies if I've overlooked anything. I'm making a plot of cruise positions, and I am getting a double-parallel happening at 60 degrees North, with one being a straight line (on a stereographic projection).

Does anybody know what I'm doing to cause this?

My plotting script (referencing external data):

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import csv

dataFile = sys.argv[1]
dataStream = open(dataFile, 'rb')
dataReader = csv.reader(dataStream, delimiter=',')
numRows = sys.argv[2]

dataLat = []
dataLon = []

dataReader.next()
for row in dataReader:
    dataLon.append(float(row[5]))
    dataLat.append(float(row[6]))

m = Basemap(width=450000,height=150000,
        resolution='f',projection='stere',\
        lat_ts=65.4,lat_0=60.4,lon_0=1.91)

m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.2)
m.fillcontinents(color='white', lake_color='aqua')

x, y = m(dataLat,dataLon)
m.scatter(x,y,.5,marker='.',color='k')

m.drawparallels(np.arange(0.,81,1.), labels=[1,0,0,0], fontsize=10)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,181.,5.), labels=[0,0,0,1], fontsize=10)
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')

plt.title("Cruise Track")
plt.show()
```

**Example:**
[image: Example plot]

One other small question: what are the units of the width / height of the plot? It does not appear to be in the documentation, and I can't find it mentioned on any tutorials, etc.

Comment: The definition of `m` seems to be missing. Do you get the double parallels if you only call `m.drawparallels(...` and then `plt.show()`?

Comment: Just added the definition; it looks like I did a poor copy-paste job. It appears that `m.drawparallels` takes _at least_ two arguments.

Comment: Also, THANKS Mr. Squido for adding my figure to the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a bug due to trying to fix another one.

I don't use basemap, but the first step to try and solve problems is to reduce them as much as possible:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

scale = 1
m = Basemap(width=450000*scale,height=150000,
        resolution='i',projection='stere',
        lat_ts=65.4,lat_0=60.4,lon_0=1.91)

parallels = [60]
ret = m.drawparallels(parallels)
plt.show()
```

You can see in the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.drawparallels) that `drawparallels` returns a dict, and we can recover the actual Line2D (the parallel) and its data points:

```
l = ret[60][0][0]
x, y = l.get_data()
```

If we have a look at the points, it doesn't look bad unless we link them, and then we can see the annoying double parallel!

```
plt.plot(x, y, '+')
plt.show()
```

[image: + points]

```
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image: Linked points]

Let's now try running the small example through the debugger (`python -m pdb small_example.py`).

If you step inside the call to drawparallels, you'll soon reach [this code](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/blob/master/lib/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py#L2242-2251). It doesn't look too good, so let's skip the highlighted lines (using `jump`, if you've never used the Python debugger you should read a bit about it).

And voilà, this is the result:

[image: Solved issue]

Taking into account where is the problem, it's easy to guess that changing the width or height of the map (in meters, by the way) could get rid of the problem. Indeed, setting `scale>=1.0485` works. Other combinations of width and height seem to work fine too.

Comment: Worked great! After multiplying my plot width by 1.0485, no more double-parallel. I will certainly get familiar with the python debugger too. Thanks!!!